# Concate Number and String why i get this result

Tags: java

I tried to concate a number with a String, I did it like this:

```
            int minute=7;
            String min = minute+"";

            if(min.length()==1){

                min = 0+minute+"";
            }
```

I got 7  instead 07 as result. Why?

Comment: change `0+minute` to `0+min`.

Comment: ah ok i unterstand, the compiler try to add 0+7 and convert it to String this why i got 7 as result. 0+""+minute will work too.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its due to the order of operation. The 0 + 7 gets executed before the 7 + "" so it is doing addition on two ints instead of concatenating them. Change the order of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

0 and minute are both integers, they are evaluated as integer addition first instead of string concatenation.

Change to:

```
min = 0 + "" + minute+"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(min.length() == 1){
    min = "0" + minute;
}
```

To write your numbers with 2 digits, you can also do:

```
int minute = 7;
String s = String.format("%02d", minute);  // 07
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly integers minute and 0 are added, and then they are casting to string.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
0+minute+""
```

is

```
0+7+""
```

which is

```
7+""
```

because `0+7==7`.

On the other hand:

```
"0"+minute
```

is

```
"0"+7
```

which is

```
"07"
```

Answer (score 1):

Operations are executed from left to right: so, 0 (an int) + min (another int) gives an int, 7.
Then, 7 (an int) + "" (a string) gives a string.

A soulution could be "0"+min

Otherwise, I suggest to use java.text.NumberFormat class to define numer formats